# How can I prevent stubborn mildew on an outdoor fir plank ceiling?

Tags: mold, stain, porch

This is mildew on the underside of a porch ceiling stained with Rubio Hybrid Wood Protector with extra M1 Mildewcide added. The substrate is Douglas Fir, which was stored under cover, then sanded and stained on the bench, prior to installing in Aug 2023. Zero water exposure - except for our copious morning dew (central TX).

I've removed mildew in this exact situation (same stain, same building), except the substrate was Southern Pine, using diluted bleach. But I've never seen mildew here that looks quite like this -- and *nothing* will get it off. I tried diluted bleach at the usual dwell time before scrubbing, then 20 min, 30 min, and 1 hour. I tried 70% alcohol, hydrogen peroxide, vinegar, and pure bleach. I could try your favorite magic cleaner... but it's hard to imagine when bleach does *nothing* (except wear the surface of the wood).

Thoughts? Again the only variable (compared to situations in which I got the mildew off no problem w/bleach solution) is that it's Douglas Fir.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Power washer. Which may also do nothing except wear the surface of the wood. You may be stuck with *going darker*. And seal it with something real this time; it won't say "protector ", it will say, polyurethane, lacquer, varnish, or shellac. Or be dark enough that this doesn't matter because you can't tell. - Basically: random orbit sander and start over (80 and then some 120. Then 220 if it's still fuzzy). Those stains are between a 32nd and a 16th deep.

Comment: Lacquer, shellac, and most varnishes do not work well exterior in this hot/humid climate. Exterior polys can be ok. The stain I used is a high quality product I've used with great success, including on the building next door (which occasionally gets mildew, but bleach gets it off right away). Hand-sanding with 80 grit exposed bare wood in 5 seconds, so I'm thinking max depth is a bit less than 1/32". But again, the mystery to me is why bleach isn't removing it (when it does fine on the next-door building with the same stain... only that wood is southern pine, not Doug fir).

Comment: I've seen that on joists inside. There's no 'cleaning' it. Hand sanded in 5s tells me there's nothing there it has to fight to get to the wood. I recommended every *real* wood finish I could think of because *any* of those is better than these, *I don't want it shiny*, products. I didn't say you wouldn't have to redo it every two years, but there won't be any mold ;)